# Naive height of the truncation of taylor series of the exponential

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $\alpha\in\overline{\mathbb Q}$. One calls naive height of $\alpha$ and one notes $H(\alpha)$ the maximum of the $|a_i|$ ($0\le i\le d$) where $P(X)=a_dX^d+a_{d-1}X^{d-1}+\cdots+a_0$ is the unique polynomial with coefficients in $\mathbb Z$ relatively prime with least degree such that $P(\alpha)=0$. Consider for every $k\in\mathbb N$, $S_k(\alpha)=\sum_{j=0}^k\frac{\alpha^j}{j!}$. Can one obtain a better estimate of $H(S_k(\alpha))$ than this one obtained by applying the rough estimates of height? Maybe one could take advantage of the fact that $k!$ is a denominator of all the terms of the sum.